# Add ref to list

Tags: c#, wpf, list, user-controls, ref

I've read places that Controls cannot be loaded into an array or list and accessed in this manner, but I'm intrigued.

My problem is as follows: I am displaying a week's worth of forecast data within my application. The forecast data is retrieved from [Wunderground's JSON API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs) and stored into an object that contains the fields necessary for display (high/low temps, condition summary, etc). My app uses the Bing maps API to perform a geocoded search and the lat/long retrieved from the Bing Maps control is passed to the request to Wunderground's service to retrieve forecast data based on a lat/long coordinate. The response contains a list of "ForecastDay" objects, which hold the forecast data for each day.

Each day is displayed in its own custom user control, and I have named them accordingly as such: forecastDay1, forecastDay2, and so on.

I'm curious as to if there's a way to add these controls to a list by reference sort of like

```
forecastDayControls.Add(ref forecastDay1);
```

so I can iterate through the controls and populate them with information based on the corresponding day, each of which has been already been put into a list by the JSON deserialization. My code is perfectly functional, but it'd be nice and pretty looking

```
for(int i = 0; i < forecastDayControls.Count; i++)
{
    forecastDayControls[0].ForecastDay = forecastDay[0];
}
```

if I could get them into a list and handle them that way, instead of going through 1 by 1 and having ugly code:

```
forecastDay1 = forecast.forecastDay[0];
forecastDay2 = forecast.forecastDay[1];
forecastDay3 = forecast.forecastDay[2];
forecastDay4 = forecast.forecastDay[3];
forecastDay5 = forecast.forecastDay[4];
forecastDay6 = forecast.forecastDay[5];
forecastDay7 = forecast.forecastDay[6];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you even tried out what you're asking? Should work unless ForecastDay is a value type...

Comment: fcdaylist.Add(ref forecastDay1);
"Argument 1 should not be passed with the ref keyword"

Comment: Try your code without the ref. Reference types are passed by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
forecastDayControls.Add(forecastDay1);
```

You do not need the `ref` keyword, because `forecastDay1` is a `class` and therefore it is always passed by reference.

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you for the explanation as well, appreciate it!